# Git thinks every file modified because of timestamp difference -- how to fix?

Tags: windows, git

I'm moving a repository between 2 Windows servers, so I zipped up the whole repository on the old server and unzipped it on the new server -- no other changes.

However the 2 servers have different timezones, so all the file timestamps on the new server are off by exactly 3 hours (the difference in timezones).

As a result Git thinks that every single file is modified, even though it isn't.

How can I make Git overlook this and/or reset what it thinks the timestamps should be?

I need it to correctly show there are no modified files at the moment.

I tried `git reset --hard` but that made no difference.

Other questions on SO seemed to address line ending or file permissions problems, which isn't the case here.  Couldn't find anything address timezone/timestamp differences.

Thanks!

Comment: Git doesn't consider timestamps, AFAIK.  What does `git diff` say?

Comment: Why zip and unzip it? Although it shouldn't create any issues, the best way is to create a remote and sync both servers.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth oh.... according to `git diff` the file permissions did change, which I didn't realize.  I did `git config core.fileMode false` and now it shows no modified files.  Sheesh :(

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth thank you for that.  Don't know why I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use git bundle in order to replicate repository.

#### On your local machine

Sample code:

```
// Create git bundle with the name of project.bundle
// --all is for packing all the local branches as well
git bundle create project.bundle --all
```

---

#### New machine

---

#### Extract the project:

Transfer `project.bundle` to the target machine B.

Because this bundle does not require any existing object to be extracted, you can create a new repository on machine B by cloning from it directly:

```
git clone -b <branch name> file.bundle <path to repository location>
```

#### Set the upstream to track changes from remote

```
git remote add origin <url>
```